Can anybody provide sample content for the SAP - SuccesFactors EC mapping table T77SFEC_EXTMAP?
I am currently working for a client who wants to setup SuccessFactors EC and integrate it in HCM. I am currently exploring the API and would be happy if someone could share sample content of the mapping table T77SFEC_EXTMAP which maps data from SF to HCM infotypes.
I would like to make an API request from the ABAP backend and then map the response to HCM infotypes. In order to respect the mapping I need the global mapping information and not do it on my own. However my client didn't setup EC yet.
